Reading symbols in arm-none-eabi-gdb takes a very long time
I have been facing some issues with arm-none-eabi-gdb taking a very long time (~40s) to read symbols from a small ELF-file. I only see this on one computer, on all other I have tested, it takes just a couple of seconds.
I have tried to enable more debugging in gdb but am no closer to finding a reason for this. This is basically what I see:
> arm-none-eabi-gdb
GNU gdb (Arm GNU Toolchain 13.3.Rel1 (Build arm-13.24)) 14.2.90.20240526-git
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://bugs.linaro.org/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb) set verbose on
(gdb) set debug symbol 1
(gdb) set debug symfile 1
(gdb) set debug solib 1
(gdb) set debug symtab-create 1
(gdb) set debug auto-load 1
(gdb) set debug symbol-lookup 1
(gdb) set debug skip 1
(gdb) set debug timestamp 1
(gdb)
(gdb) file stm32_sample.elf
Reading symbols from stm32_sample.elf...
1731503511.198257 sf->sym_new_init (stm32_sample.elf)
1731503511.201257 sf->sym_init (stm32_sample.elf)
1731503511.203756 sf->sym_offsets (stm32_sample.elf, 0x194f730)
1731503511.206261 sf->sym_read (stm32_sample.elf, 0xe)
1731503511.210774 [symtab-create] elf_read_minimal_symbols: reading minimal symbols of objfile C:\temp_st\stm32_sample\build\Debug\stm32_sample.elf
1731503511.214273 [symtab-create] install: installing 107 minimal symbols of objfile C:\temp_st\stm32_sample\build\Debug\stm32_sample.elf
1731503511.217774 [symtab-create] elf_read_minimal_symbols: done reading minimal symbols
1731503511.220273 qf->has_symbols (stm32_sample.elf) = 1
1731503555.187064 qf->has_symbols (stm32_sample.elf) = 1
1731503555.189570 [auto-load] auto_load_objfile_script_1: Attempted file "C:\temp_st\stm32_sample\build\Debug\stm32_sample.elf-gdb.gdb" does not exist.
1731503555.191580 [auto-load] auto_load_objfile_script_1: Searching 'set auto-load scripts-directory' path "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
1731503555.193508 [auto-load] auto_load_objfile_script_1: Attempted file "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load\C\temp_st\stm32_sample\build\Debug\stm32_sample.elf-gdb.gdb" does not exist.
1731503555.195008 [symbol-lookup] lookup_minimal_symbol: lookup_minimal_symbol (__gnat_ada_main_program_name, NULL, stm32_sample.elf)
1731503555.196535 [symbol-lookup] lookup_minimal_symbol: lookup_minimal_symbol (...) = NULL
1731503555.199052 [symbol-lookup] lookup_minimal_symbol: lookup_minimal_symbol (D main, NULL, stm32_sample.elf)
1731503555.201622 [symbol-lookup] lookup_minimal_symbol: lookup_minimal_symbol (...) = NULL
1731503555.203744 [symbol-lookup] lookup_minimal_symbol: lookup_minimal_symbol (main.main, NULL, stm32_sample.elf)
1731503555.207395 [symbol-lookup] lookup_minimal_symbol: lookup_minimal_symbol (...) = NULL
1731503555.210594 [symbol-lookup] lookup_minimal_symbol: lookup_minimal_symbol (_p_initialize, NULL, stm32_sample.elf)
1731503555.213301 [symbol-lookup] lookup_minimal_symbol: lookup_minimal_symbol (...) = NULL
1731503555.215357 [symbol-lookup] lookup_minimal_symbol: lookup_minimal_symbol (__jit_debug_register_code, NULL, stm32_sample.elf)
1731503555.218507 [symbol-lookup] lookup_minimal_symbol: lookup_minimal_symbol (...) = NULL
1731503555.220622 probes->sym_get_probes (stm32_sample.elf) = 0x0
1731503555.221606 [symbol-lookup] lookup_minimal_symbol: lookup_minimal_symbol (std::terminate(), NULL, stm32_sample.elf)
1731503555.226565 [symbol-lookup] lookup_minimal_symbol: lookup_minimal_symbol (...) = NULL
1731503555.228782 probes->sym_get_probes (stm32_sample.elf) = 0x0
1731503555.230566 [symbol-lookup] lookup_minimal_symbol: lookup_minimal_symbol (_Unwind_DebugHook, NULL, stm32_sample.elf)
1731503555.233614 [symbol-lookup] lookup_minimal_symbol: lookup_minimal_symbol (...) = NULL
(gdb)

As you can see, the reading of minimal symbols takes no time. It is between the two qf->has_symbols where it spends ~40 secs.
The ELF-file I use to test this was created by using STM32CubeMX. I selected a basic MCU (STM32F072) and enabled no peripherals. I set the project files to use CMake and generated the code. I then used CMake in VSCode to build the ELF-file. The resulting ELF-file is ~680kB.
Has anyone seen anything similar? Seeing as I have only seen it on my computer, it could be environment related, but what part in that case?
Are there more debug things to enable in gdb to get more info?
I have tried using ARM GNU tools 13.3, 13.2, 12.2, all produce approximately the same results. I am running Windows 11 Pro, and tested in both cmd and cygwin.

If you are able to share the binary then you might consider raising a bug report with the GDB project here: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/  Be sure to include the version of GDB you are using, which you can view using the show version command.

Meet the same problem on my windows 10. Looking forward for more clues here
